Completely confused by に無断で
メアリーは母に無断でケーキを作った。
I still don't get the ni particle with the 無断で word. The only explanation I can give to myself is that the ni particle means ''from'' here but I still am not able to make sense of it. Some other sources say it is an action done towards the target but that just doesn't make sense in this context to me.

If you are thinking Mary made the cake to Mother, it's incorrect.
無断で means without giving a notice, and 母に here connects with it as the person to(に) whom the notice is made. So 母に無断で means without letting Mother know.

Without notice makes much more sense since you are actively (not doing the action of) communicating with her. Thanks for the feedback!
